# Javascript, convert unicode string to Javascript escape?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unicode

I have a variable that contains a string consisting of Japanese characters, for instance;

**"みどりいろ"**

How would I go about converting this to its Javascript escape form?

The result I am after for this example specifically is:

**"\u306f\u3044\u3044\u308d"**

I'd prefer a jquery approach if there's a variation.

Comment: @SergeiZahharenko - `escape("abc") //"abc"`...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
"み".charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
```

This will give you the unicode (in Hex). You can run it through a loop:

```
String.prototype.toUnicode = function(){
    var result = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
        // Assumption: all characters are < 0xffff
        result += "\\u" + ("000" + this[i].charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).substr(-4);
    }
    return result;
};

"みどりいろ".toUnicode();       //"\u307f\u3069\u308a\u3044\u308d"
"Mi Do Ri I Ro".toUnicode();  //"\u004d\u0069\u0020\u0044\u006f\u0020\u0052\u0069\u0020\u0049\u0020\u0052\u006f"
"Green".toUniCode();          //"\u0047\u0072\u0065\u0065\u006e"
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/X7MCy/

More on: [`.charCodeAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt)

Comment: My bad :) For some reason I missed the `.toString(16)` part

Comment: @EladStern - It's okay.

Comment: You can replace `while(partial.length !== 4) partial = "0" + partial;` with `('0000' + partial).substr(-4);` which I would prefer :)

Comment: @Adassko - Ooo nice idea.

Comment: You can also replace your loop with a `replace` function. Then the whole function will be: `return this.replace(/./g, function(c) { return "\\u" + ('000' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).substr(-4) });` :P

Comment: @Adassko - I didn't really thought of it, but I think creating a new anonymous function for each character would be slower and consume more memory than a `for` loop. [(It would be very minimal though, about 5% slower)](http://jsperf.com/looping-through-a-string)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: it creates new function only once, then just calls it for every character. No doubt it will be a little bit slower (especially that it uses regular expression) but that's should bother anyone

Comment: Interesting thing is that when you change `this[i].charCodeAt(0)` to `this.charCodeAt(i)` it will be even slower than the version with `replace` :O

Comment: looks like using `map` is the fastest if you look on performance thought: http://jsperf.com/looping-through-a-string/2

Comment: @Adassko That's interesting. Maybe .charCodeAt has a different character selecting algorithm or maybe the whole string has to be copied into the method before processing, making it slower.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 i have Hex Unicode, How can convert Hex Unicode to normal text??

Comment: @SantoshJadi How is it represented?

Comment: You should never ever extend `prototype` of built-in classes. Suppose the Ecma TC39 would want to add `toUnicode` function. Well if many people will use this then now they cannot.

Comment: @Nux This answer was written in a time when extending the prototype was still a fairly common practice, but the landscape has since changed and you should probably export the function as a module instead.

Answer (score 12):

Above answer is reasonable. A slight space and performance optimization:

```
function escapeUnicode(str) {
    return str.replace(/[^\0-~]/g, function(ch) {
        return "\\u" + ("000" + ch.charCodeAt().toString(16)).slice(-4);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

just

```
escape("みどりいろ")
```

should meet the needs for most cases, buf if you need it in the form of "\u" instead of "%xx" / "%uxxxx" then you might want to use regular expressions:

<s>`escape("みどりいろ").replace(/%/g, '\\').toLowerCase()`</s>

```
escape("みどりいろ").replace(/%u([A-F0-9]{4})|%([A-F0-9]{2})/g, function(_, u, x) { return "\\u" + (u || '00' + x).toLowerCase() });
```

(`toLowerCase` is optional to make it look exactly like in the first post)

It doesn't escape characters it doesn't need to in most cases which may be a plus for you; if not - see Derek's answer, or use my version:

```
'\\u' + "みどりいろ".split('').map(function(t) { return ('000' + t.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).substr(-4) }).join('\\u');
```

Comment: Upvoted because this works too (only for characters other than latin letters and common punctuation marks.)

Comment: Fails for characters in the range U+0000 to U+001F, U+007F to U+00FF plus various punctuation marks. These characters get `escape`d to `%xx` instead of `%uxxxx`, which results in invalid backslash escapes. You would have to do two replacements, one for `%u` to `\u` and then one for `%` to `\x`. Also the `toLowerCase()` is superfluous and would lose information for unescaped characters.

Comment: does this pass [The Pile of Poo Test™](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode#poo-test) ? :P

Answer (score 1):

My version of code, based on previous answers. I use if to convert non UTF8 chars in JSON.stringify().

```
const toUTF8 = string =>
    string.split('').map(
        ch => !ch.match(/^[^a-z0-9\s\t\r\n_|\\+()!@#$%^&*=?/~`:;'"\[\]\-]+$/i)
            ? ch
            : '\\' + 'u' + '000' + ch.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)
    ).join('');
```

Usage:

```
JSON.stringify({key: 'Категория дли импорта'}, (key, value) => {
    if (typeof value === "string") {
        return toUTF8(value);
    }

    return value;
});
```

Returns JSON:

```
{"key":"\\u00041a\\u000430\\u000442\\u000435\\u000433\\u00043e\\u000440\\u000438\\u00044f \\u000434\\u00043b\\u000438 \\u000438\\u00043c\\u00043f\\u00043e\\u000440\\u000442\\u000430"}
```

Comment: Those \u sequences make no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the encodeURI function:

```
encodeURI("みどりいろ")
"%E3%81%BF%E3%81%A9%E3%82%8A%E3%81%84%E3%82%8D"
```

And the other side decode it back:

```
decodeURI("%E3%81%BF%E3%81%A9%E3%82%8A%E3%81%84%E3%82%8D")
"みどりいろ"
```

Answer (score -1):

I have an answer for this question. This function I made worked for me. To encode only the non utf-8 characters to Unicode.

```
function toUnicode(word){
       let array = word.split("");
       array =  array.map((character)=>{
                if(character.match(/[^a-zA-Z]/g)){
                    let conversion = "000" + character.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)
                    return "\\u" + conversion;
                 }
                 return character;
});
return array.join("")
}
```

Comment: This works for some characters but for "higher" characters like ✓ it doesn't. The code from Adam Leggett below https://stackoverflow.com/a/40558081/3434804 gets the job done.