# Send Emoji as text in a SMS message

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unicode, sms, emoji

I'm curious is this possible. 
I want to send an SMS message from a web application (AngularJS) and want to be able to send emojis. Is it possible to send the emoji as it's unicode representation as plain text

Example: Hello U+1F601 
Would display: Hello

Obviously sending this as text will not work. I'll just recieve Hello U+1F601

Is this possible by somehow prefixing or wrapping the unicode somehow?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21014476/javascript-convert-unicode-string-to-javascript-escape for a discussion of unicode and Javascript

Comment: Follow on question if I was to send that hex on my phone would it display as an emoji?

Comment: How are you actually sending the SMS? Whatever service you're passing the string to should handle the encoding...

Comment: I'm not sure of the capabilities of the service that is being used (mblox). I'm just curious as a starting point if I could send a string of text on my phone that would be translated to an emoji by the reciever

Comment: Having researched a little more the character sets they support are
GSM 03.38 encoding and
Latin 1 (ISO-8859-1) encoding

Guessing this might mean no dice

Comment: Have you tried actually sending that encoded character?

Comment: Haven't tried yet, this idea came to me when I left the office

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should be able to do it - although the platform you are using may not support it.

Emoji are in the unicode standard (UTF-16) http://unicode.org/emoji/

Although not all emoji are supported by all phones (so the receiver's device may use an SMS app that cannot properly translate the emoji)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: Why do you say that? There isn't a need or requirement to wrap a Unicode character, nor would it help unless the target platform is known and specific. I've written text messaging apps, and it works. Although some platforms support different Unicode Emoji characters, as I mentioned